# What is the common practice of uninstalling the developer or enterprise edition of TigerGraph?

Tags: graph, graph-databases, tigergraph

We are experimenting with TigerGraph for a graph database solution. In the processes of testing we have switch from developer edition to enterprise edition. We wanted to know if there is a best practice on uninstalling TigerGraph.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps below to uninstall tigergraph:

1) switch to tigergraph user (assuming  it is "tigergraph"):

```
su - tigergraph
```

2) uninstall platform:

```
guninstall
```